# Ms Access SQL Limit control by previous field value

Tags: sql, ms-access, controls, where-clause

In a recipe database I have two tables. One has the ingredients of every recipe [Recipe_ingr] and the other the available measures and weight for every ingredient [Weight2].

When I input a new ingredient for a recipe, I would like to be able to choose the available units for only that specific food.

I have tried with this expression in the control field but it prompts me to choose first, and then the options remain the same for all the records, not changing dinamically according to the record ingredient code.

```
SELECT [Weight2].[Msre_Desc], [Weight2].[Gm_Wgt] FROM Weight2 WHERE Weight2.NDB_No Like Recipe_Ingr.NDB_No ORDER BY [Msre_Desc], [Gm_Wgt];
```

[Picture of my tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ccF.png)

Update:

I tried the syntax change suggested by June9 but still the control doesn't update automatically with every record as you can see in this picture: [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObiyO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you name controls different from fields they are bound to, like tbxNDB. The SQL needs to reference a field or control that is on the form. Also, LIKE operator without wildcard accomplishes nothing that an = sign wouldn't. Also recommend not using exactly same name for fields in multiple tables.

If you use that SQL statement in combobox RowSource, try:

`SELECT Msre_Desc, Gm_Wgt FROM Weight2 WHERE NDB_No = [tbxNDB] ORDER BY Msre_Desc, Gm_Wgt;`

You want to save Msre_Desc as foreign key, not a record id generated by autonumber?

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying your syntax, and I changed the field name to tbxNDB as you suggested in the ingredients table. But now, the control box is empty. About your question, I am not actually saving the measure description but their weight in grams. American measures based on volume are awful for conversions.

Comment: Did not suggest changing field name, but the textbox bound to that field. Or if it is a combobx, like cbxNDB. Your db has only 2 tables? Didn't I recommend 3 tables in your other question?

Comment: Furthermore, I fixed some formatting and the result it is still the same, Access prompts me to choose the value for tbxNDB and then every control box in the "unit" field shows the same control from Msre_Desc

Comment: Uhm, sorry, I will need to try to change the textbox name then. Yes, I have more than 3 tables.

Comment: Do some research on cascading (dependent) combo and list boxes. Here is one http://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut10.htm. The RowSource can be set to the SQL in design view or use VBA to set.

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to have a look on that, and learn more, I'll keep you updated. Thank you so much again!

Comment: And another http://www.datapigtechnologies.com/flashfiles/combobox2.html

Comment: This video helped me solving my question in a very intuitive way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpMyGlEInGs